# Open Source Terminal Server for Mac OS X

Tags: untagged

Our Company developes mobile application for Apple Iphone. We require more Apple PCs. Because Our work is only in XCode We plan to deploy a Terminal Server for MAC.

Is there any open Source Terminal Server for MAC OS X ?

Comment: Are you looking for an OSS solution or free software?

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS X has an embeded VNC server.
There is no way to use more than 1 graphical session at a time, event remotely.
The only possible things would be to open localy a graphical session for each user (Fast User Switching) and run an instance of VPN in each session (see http://www.redstonesoftware.com/multidesktop.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Aqua Connect with Terminal Server. I have not tried the software yet but hope to test it in the near future. If someone has experience with it, please post as well.

ACTS 2.0 and 3.1 delivers the Macintosh OS X experience to diverse hardware, software platforms and mobile devices. Users can simply log into the OS X server as if connected directly to the server’s console, work with a full-featured OS X desktop and run OS X based applications. All user sessions are fully isolated from one another.
http://www.aquaconnect.net/