# how to configure mac os x as a terminal server?

Tags: mac-osx

Our company's primary business is software or website development.  For software or website testing we require different browsers in Mac, Linux and Windows. For Linux we used Ulteo-Desktop. I want to know how to configure Mac OS X as terminal server which allows multiple users to log in to terminal server and check software or website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/8966/mac-os-x-multi-user-thin-client-server-terminal-server

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Open Source Terminal Server for Mac OS X](https://serverfault.com/questions/61061/open-source-terminal-server-for-mac-os-x/61063#61063)